# How to remove "price suffix" from woocommerce order

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering how I could remove the following from my woo-commerce orders.

When someone orders from my website they are asked to:

[image: When someone is placing an order they are asked to enter some info]

When they order the information that they entered shows up in order description:

[image: This is the order description]

As you can see there is a price suffix "(+€0,00)" after the user input. How do I remove this? The reason I need this removed is because this shows up in a .csv file that I need to use to process the user input. But how would I approach in removing this so called suffix?

Comment: This is sort of nooby but what about just CSS - display: none;?

Answer (score 0):

I would post a comment to ask for some more information, seeing as I am a little confused and do not speak whatever language this site was written in. In addition, it would be useful to see the js code. However, I need 50 rep to do that, yet none to answer the question. My idea is to use all the code that is built up to this point. Create a separate part that substrings out and trims to just have the numbers, then sends that to the CSV file after. The other part would be to keep it as is, and send the same information unedited so it's somewhat easier for you to see when you see that page. I would add more, if I could see the code inside and see where the price suffix coming from is.